# What is %~ (percent tilde) in ZSH?

Tags: macos, shell, zsh

I'm trying to customize [this](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/blob/master/themes/agnoster.zsh-theme) oh-my-zsh theme.

I found this piece of code in it, which apparently prints the dir name (correct me if I'm wrong).

```
# Dir: current working directory
prompt_dir() {
  prompt_segment blue black '%~'
}
```

and prompt_segment is defined as

```
# Begin a segment
# Takes two arguments, background and foreground. Both can be omitted,
# rendering default background/foreground.
prompt_segment() {
  local bg fg
  [[ -n $1 ]] && bg="%K{$1}" || bg="%k"
  [[ -n $2 ]] && fg="%F{$2}" || fg="%f"
  if [[ $CURRENT_BG != 'NONE' && $1 != $CURRENT_BG ]]; then
    echo -n " %{$bg%F{$CURRENT_BG}%}$SEGMENT_SEPARATOR%{$fg%} "
  else
    echo -n "%{$bg%}%{$fg%} "
  fi
  CURRENT_BG=$1
  [[ -n $3 ]] && echo -n $3
}
```

The output of this isn't always just the directory path. If I'm in a path which is also present in an ENV variable, it replaces the path with that variable.

If I'm in

```
/Users/abc/.oh-my-zsh/custom
```

And $ZSH_CUSTOM is

```
/Users/abc/.oh-my-zsh/custom
```

I just get `$ZSH_CUSTOM` in the command prompt.

So my question is, 1) what's the `%~` being sent from `prompt_dir`, 2) where is this piece of coding getting the current working directory from, and 3) how can I make it *always* output the real path.

Comment: Thank you for asking this. I also was trying to edit the agnoster theme because the directory prompt gets way to big. Changing '%~' to '%2d' worked perfectly.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

See `EXPANSION OF PROMPT SEQUENCES` section of `man zshmisc`:

> ```
>    %d
>    /      Current  working  directory.   If an integer follows the `%', it
>           specifies a number of trailing components of the current working
>           directory  to show; zero means the whole path.  A negative inte‐
>           ger specifies leading components, i.e. %-1d specifies the  first
>           component.
>
>    %~     As  %d  and %/, but if the current working directory has a named
>           directory as its prefix, that part is replaced by a `~' followed
>           by  the  name  of  the directory.  If it starts with $HOME, that
>           part is replaced by a `~'.
> ```

Comment: Excellent :). One more wish - can I replace my home dir with a `~` in conjunction with using `%d`? I would like to have the full path, minus `$HOME` being replaced by `~`.

Comment: @user1527166 Isn’t it exactly what `%~` does? Most of time you don’t hit “named directory as its prefix” case unless you are constantly using them via named directories hash or special function (don’t remember its name).

Comment: use `${PWD/~/\~}`